# Where can I find the various operating limitations of the ATR 72-500?

Tags: aircraft-limitations, atr-72

Where can I find the various operating limitations of the [ATR 72-500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_72)? Is there any document that lists them?

Comment: Are you talking about Limitations? If yes, that information is in POH/AIM.

Comment: YES, i am looking for limitations, can i get any documents other than flight manual?

Answer (score 2):

> LIMITATIONS
>
> PAGE : 001 APR 11 EASA APPROVED
>
> Model : 212 A 
>   AFM 1
>
> ---
>
> ***2.01.01*** | INTRODUCTION
>
> Observance of the limitations contained in this chapter is required by law. When
>   operating in accordance with an approved appendix or supplement to
>   this manual, the limitations of this basic Airplane Flight Manual
>   section apply, except as altered by such an appendix or supplement.
>
> ***2.01.02*** | KINDS OF OPERATION
>
> The airplane is certified in the
>   Transport Category, JAR 25 and ICAO annex 16 for day and night
>   operations, in the following conditions when the appropriate equipment
>   and instruments required by the airworthiness and operating
>   regulations are approved, installed and in an operable condition :
>
> - VFR and IFR
> - Flight in icing conditions.
> - Reverse thrust taxi (single or twin engine)
>
> ***2.01.03*** | MINIMUM FLIGHT CREW
>
> 2 pilots
>
> ***2.01.04*** | PERFORMANCE CONFIGURATION
>
> Refer to 6.01.03 for airplane configuration associated with certified
>   performances.
>
> ***2.01.05*** | MAXIMUM OPERATING ALTITUDE
>
> 25000 ft
>
> ***2.01.06*** | MANEUVERING LIMIT LOAD FACTORS
>
> - Gear and flaps retracted : + 2.5 to -- 1 g
> - Gear and/or flaps extended : + 2 to 0 g
>
> ***2.01.07*** | CONFIGURATION DEVIATION LIST
>
> Refer to 7.01.02
>
> ***2.01.08*** | NOISE CHARACTERISTICS
>
> The aircraft meets the requirements of ICAO annex 16,
>   Chapter 4 with no weight restriction. Refer to noise characteristics
>   in Appendix 7.01.01 of this manual for noise levels.
>
> ***2.01.09*** | MAXIMUM NUMBER OF PASSENGER SEATS
>
> 74 as limited by emergency exits
>   configuration
>
> ***2.02.01*** | WEIGHTS
>
> STRUCTURAL LIMITATIONS
>
> MAXIMUM WEIGHT KG LB
>
> - RAMP 22970 50640
> - TAKE-OFF 22800 50265
> - LANDING 22350 49273
> - ZERO FUEL 20800 45856
>
> PERFORMANCE LIMITATIONS
>
> Maximum take-off weight and maximum landing weight may be reduced by performance
>   requirements related to the following (see chapter 6) :
>
> - climb performance (first and second segment, final take-off and en route, approach and landing climb)
> - available runway length (take-off and landing)
> - tyre limit speed
> - brake energy limit, observe BRK TEMP alert for take-off
> - obstacle clearance (take-off and en route)
> - en route and landing weight
>
> ***2.03.01*** | AIRSPEEDS
>
> - MAXIMUM OPERATING SPEED VMO / MMO
>
>   This limit must not be intentionally exceeded in any flight regime.
>
>   - VMO = 250 kt CAS
>   - MMO = 0.55
> - MAXIMUM DESIGN MANEUVERING SPEED VA
>
>   Full application of roll and yaw controls, as well as maneuvers that involve angles of attack near the stall
>     should be confined to speeds below VA.
>
>   - VA = 175 kt CAS
>
>   CAUTION: Rapidly alternating large rudder applications in combination with
>     large sideslip angles may result in structural failure at any speed.
> - MAXIMUM FLAPS EXTENDED OR OPERATING SPEEDS VFE
>
>   - FLAPS 15 185 kt CAS
>   - FLAPS 30 150 kt CAS
> - MAXIMUM LANDING GEAR EXTENDED OR OPERATING SPEEDS
>
>   - VLE = 185 kt CAS
>   - VLO
>   - lowering = 170 kt CAS
>   - retracting = 160 kt CAS
>
> ***2.03.02*** | OPERATIONAL PARAMETERS ENVIRONMENTAL ENVELOPE
>
> Note : Refer
>   to 2.04.05 for fuel temperature limitation. TAKE–OFF AND LANDING –
>   Tail wind limit : 15 kt – Maximum mean runway slope : ±2 %
>
> ***2.04.01*** | ENGINES
>
> PRATT&WHITNEY CANADA PW127F or PW127M or PW127N
>
> Operating limits with no unscheduled maintenance action required;
>   Beyond these limits refer to maintenance manual.
>
> OPERATING CONDITION TIME LIMIT TQ
>   (%) ITT ($^\circ$C) NH (%) NL (%) NP (%) OIL PRESS (PSI) OIL TEMP ($^\circ$C)
>   (<sup>2</sup>)
>
> RESERVE TAKE OFF 10 mn (<sup>6</sup>) 100 (<sup>1</sup>) 800 103.2 104.2 101 55 to 65 0 to 125
>
> NORMAL TAKE OFF 5 mn 90 (<sup>1</sup>) (<sup>5</sup>)
>   101.9 101.4 101 55 to 65 0 to 125
>
> MAXIMUM CONTINUOUS none (<sup>7</sup>)
>   90.9 (<sup>1</sup>) 800 103.2 104.2 101 55 to 65 0 to 125
>
> GROUND IDLE 66 mini 40 mini (<sup>4</sup>)
>   -- 40 to 125
>
> HOTEL MODE 715 55 to 65 125
>
> TRANSIENT 20 s 120 840 106.4 106.8 106 (<sup>3</sup>) 40 to 100 5 s 120 20 mn 140
>
> STARTING 5 s 950 --54 mini
>
> 1. Value linked to 100 % NP.
> 2. Oil temperature must be maintained above 45$^\circ$C to ensure protection for 
>      the engine air inlet against ice accumulation.
> 3. Permissible for completion of flight provided TQ does not exceed 75.2 %
>      during climb and 73.13 % during cruise.
> 4. Up to 75 % NH only.
> 5. ITT limits depend on outside air temperature. Refer to 2.04 page 2.
> 6. Single engine operation only, beyond 5 mn.
> 7. MCT rating is the max
>      power certified for continuous use. In-flight emergencies are the
>      only conditions for which MCT use is authorized.
>
> NOTE : Flight with an
>   engine running and the propeller feathered is not permitted
>
> ***2.04.02*** | PROPELLERS
>
> TWO HAMILTON STANDARD HS 568 F 
>    – 1 GROUND OPERATION 
>   Engine run up must be performed into the wind.  Avoid static operation
>   between 41.6 % and 62.5 % NP.  Avoid operation in feather above 66.6 %
>   TQ.
>
> GROUND OR FLIGHT OPERATION  If a propeller is involved in an
>   overspeed or in an engine overtorque refer to the propeller
>   maintenance manual.
>
> FLIGHT OPERATION  ATR airplanes are protected
>   against a positioning of power levers below the flight idle stop in
>   flight by an IDLE GATE device.  It is reminded that any attempt to
>   override this protection is prohibited. Such positioning may lead to
>   loss of airplane control or may result in an engine overspeed
>   condition and consequent loss of engine power.
>
> 04 POWER PLANT 2
>   LIMITATIONS PAGE : 001 DEC 96 EASA APPROVED
>   --Model : 212 A AFM 4 AUG 07 FEB 05 R JUL 06 SEP 06 R R R
>
> ***2.04.03*** | OILSYSTEM SPECIFICATION Refer to specification PWA 521 type II.
>
> ***2.04.04*** | STARTER
>
> 3 starts with a 1 minute 30 seconds maximum combined starter running time followed by 4 minutes OFF.
>
> ***2.04.05*** | FUELSYSTEM
>
> Acceptable fuels : Jet A, Jet A1, JP5 and RT, TS1. Use of JP4 and Jet B is prohibited.
>
> TEMPERATURE
>
> - For flight
>     preparation, a minimum fuel temperature must be taken into account to
>     ensure adequate relight :
>
>   - 3 4 o C JET A, JET A1 and RT, TS1.
>   - 2 6 o C for fuel type JP5. •Maximum temperature : 57 o C for fuel types JET A, JET A1, JP 5 and RT, TS1.
>
> REFUELING
>
> Maximum pressure 3.5
>   bars (50 PSI)
>
> USABLE FUEL
>
> The total quantity of fuel usable in each
>   tank is : 2500 kg (5510 lbs)
>
> NOTE :Fuel remaining in the tanks when
>   quantity indicators show zero is not usable in flight.
>
> UNBALANCE
>
> Maximum fuel unbalance : 730 kg (1609 lbs)
>
> FEEDING
>
> - Each electrical pump is able to supply one engine in the whole flight envelope.
> - One electrical pump and associated jet pump are able to supply both
>     engines in the whole flight envelope
>
> ***2.05.01*** | AIR PRESSURIZATION
>
> - Maximum differential pressure: 6.35 PSI
> - Maximum negative differential pressure 0.5 PSI
> - Maximum differential pressure for landing 0.35 PSI
> - Maximum differential pressure for OVBD VALVE full open selection 1 PSI
> - Maximum altitude for one bleed off operation 20000 ft
>
> ***2.05.02*** | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM
>
> All hydraulic fluids compliant with technical
>   specification : NSA 307110 Compliant fluids are listed in the AMM
>   (Chapter20, 20-31-30)
>
> ***2.05.03*** | LANDING GEAR
>
> - Do not perform pivoting (sharp turns) upon a landing gear with fully braked wheels except in case of emergency.
> - In case of ground speed over 165 kt all tires to be replaced.
> - Towbarless Towing is prohibited, unless the towbarless towing operations are performed in compliance with the appropriate
>     operational requirements (JAR--OPS--1 for Commercial Air
>     Transportation) using towbarless towing vehicles that are designed and
>     operated to preclude damage to the aeroplane nose wheel steering
>     system or which provide a reliable and unmistakable warning when
>     damage to the steering system may have occurred. Towbarless towing
>     vehicles that are specifically accepted for ATR aircraft are listed in
>     ATR Service Letter 72--09--6001.
>
> ***2.05.04*** | FLAPS
>
> Holding with any flaps extended is prohibited in icing conditions (except for single engine operations).
>
> ***2.05.05*** | AUTOMATIC FLIGHT CONTROL SYSTEM (AFCS)
>
> - Minimum height for autopilot engagement on take off : 100 ft
> - NAV mode for VOR approach, using either autopilot or flight director is authorized only if :
>
>   - a co--located DME is available, and
>   - DME HOLD is not selected
> - Minimum height for use of either autopilot or flight director :
>
>   - Except during take off or executing an approach : 1000 ft
>   - VS or IAS mode during approach : 160 ft
>   - CAT 1 APP mode : 160 ft Refer to 7.01.03 for CAT II operation
>
> ***2.05.06*** | INSTRUMENTS MARKING
>
> Red arc or radial line : minimum and maximum limits Yellow arc : caution area Green arc : normal area
>
> ***2.05.07*** | CARGO DOOR OPERATION
>
> Do not operate cargo door with a lateral wind component of more than 45 kt.
>
> .../... 05 SYSTEMS 2 LIMITATIONS PAGE : 001 AUG 14 EASA APPROVED
>   --Model : 212 A AFM 2
>
> ***2.05.08*** | ELECTRICAL
>
> Single DC GEN operation : In flight, if OAT exceeds ISA + 25, flight level must be limited to FL200.
>
> ***2.05.09*** | MFC
>
> Take off with two or more failed MFC modules is prohibited
>
> ***2.05.10*** | COMMUNICATIONS
>
> Not applicable
>
> ***2.05.11*** | TCAS
>
> When installed, Refer to appendix 7.01.0

Comment: Hello QWERTY, welcome to aviation.SE! That is a lot of text... could you improve the layout?

Comment: Can you add appropriate citation of the source? Preferably with link _if_ it is available on internet.