# Do flying boats carry anchors?

Tags: equipment, seaplane, flying-boat

Inspired by [the first comment here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42747/how-do-seaplanes-do-run-up-checks-without-brakes#comment109580_42747), and considering they are called "boats", do flying boats (or seaplanes) carry anchors?

Comment: A quick google search (I just searched for "flying boat anchor") finds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blohm_%26_Voss_BV_138 which shows an image titled *"Blohm & Voss BV 138 at anchor on Lake Siutghiol, near Constanta, Romania in 1943."* So, yes, at least some do, or at least did.

Comment: And if they carry anchors, are they different from normal heavy boat anchors? Weight is not so much as issue ona boat.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no english translation, but [the swiss law](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/19760005/index.html) regarding the swiss and german [lake constance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Constance) implies that all kinds of floating devices (except smaller rowing- and sail boats, but including seaplanes) have to carry anchors.

Comment: @Koyovis there are a multitude of anchor types; some of them rely more on mechanically getting purchase on the bottom than just using weight to remain in place.  This is equally true for say, small sailboats, where reducing weight makes the anchor both easier to store and use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to a story in [Flying Magazine Nov 1956](https://books.google.com/books?id=I3NDP6qFLxQC), the [Grumman SA-16 Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_HU-16_Albatross) in that story (see page 58) carried an anchor.

---

[image]

For pre-flight, the [FAA says](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/):

> Check that necessary marine and safety
>   equipment, such as life vests, lines (ropes), **anchors,**
>   and paddles are present, in good condition, and
>   stowed correctly.

[image]
(FAA)

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grumman_HU-16_N43155_(6194127452).jpg)) Nose access on the Albatross.

The answer seems yes.

Comment: Paddles! Never thought of that. That plane is gorgeous, where's the image from?

Comment: @DiegoSánchez - the blue one was [from here](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/2e/3e/8b2e3e430c5ddf307b831d57746c5b49.jpg). It's a Grumman G-21 Goose.

Answer (score 13):

I can confirm they had one: I was lucky enough to own an HU-16 Albatross, many years ago. Prior to my purchase the bird was down in Arizona, near the Davis-Monthan boneyard.

It still had the original Grumman issues anchor mounted in forward compartment.  What I don't remember is what material it was fabricated from:  I think it was aluminum, and remember thinking of it being novel..  but it may have been bronze.

Either way, they *definitely* came originally equipped with one.

--
The Albatross, though underpowered, was an amazingly durable bird.  Some compelling stories float around about them rescuing downed pilots in Korea and Vietnam, landing in tiny creeks and ripping the floats off on banks.

Fun fact: An albatross that had struck a submerged log and had the bottom ripped out was sent to Australia for repair.. At the facility they didn't have the correct rivets (flush head, chamfered) and so they used normal button head rivets for the repair job... After this repair, it was discovered that this Albatross was able to get off the water at lower speeds than production birds..

It was so much improved that it was sent to Pax River for study.. It turns out that the use of button head rivets enabled it to break the water stiction at very low speeds.  The Navy (and Chairforce) then had custom rivets made and replaced all HU-16 lower hull rivets with them. They were custom because they had that chamfer.. So if you look at an Albatross rivet you will see that unique button-head with flush chamfer profile.